# troubles with enumerate() in for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I have a list that contains indices and a list that contains values.
I want to check, whether the value at the given position of the index is bigger or smaller than the value that is at the index-1 position in the list.
I then want my function to return the index of the value that is smaller - so either the input index or the input-index-1.
For testing purposes I have created these:

```
indices = [2,5,8,11] 
values = [3,10,15,4,20,30,24,11,10,2,12,8,7] 
my_list = []
```

I set up a for-loop that does almost what I want but it appends the value itself, not it's index. It looks like this:

```
for i in indices:
    if values[i] > values[i-1]:
        my_list.append(values[i-1])
    else: 
        my_list.append(values[i])
```

Which gives the output

```
my_list = [10, 20, 10, 8]
```

I then tried using enumerate for this purpose but it returns an error.

```
my_list1 = []        


for i,x in enumerate(indices):
    if values[i] > values[i-1]:
        my_list1.append(indices[x-1])
    else: 
        my_list1.append(indices[x])
```

the wanted output would be:

```
my_list1 = [1,4,8,11]
```

Comment: First iteration i == 0, you try values[i-1] ... think about it....

Answer (score 1):

You were close, simply use `i` instead of `values[i]` to append the index:

```py
for i in indices:
    if values[i] > values[i-1]:
        my_list.append(i-1)
    else: 
        my_list.append(i)
```